# Wordpress remove CSS content with custom CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm using the most recent version of Wordpress in combination with a theme.
On that theme there is some css code I don't need/want and which makes my customized page look bad. This would be one example:

```
#content table {
    border: 0;
    margin: 0 0px 24px 0;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#content tr {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

So far I always commented out such parts directly on the style.css of that theme. But like that I'll always loose my changes whenever I update that theme.

Now I've started to bring all my changes into the custom css directory of that theme. This works good for changes, however I have no idea how to remove the part I'm usually commenting out.

Any idea how to do that?

This question aims also to such changes where I'm commenting out parts of that style:

```
#content tr td {
border-top: 1px solid transparent;
/*
padding: 6px 24px;
vertical-align:top;
*/
}
```

Hopefully you understand what I mean :)

Comment: Create a child theme.https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Comment: Try to use `!important` at your CSS code.

Comment: Thanks but using a child theme doesn't seem to solve my issue. Even with a child-theme it looks like it's loading my old style.css - meaning I can't remove code from the css like i.e. #content tr { vertical-align: top; }

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a child theme and then import the functions.php and style.css in it.
Then add your changes here.
You will never lose it whenever you will update your theme.
Please let me know if you want code too...

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that, but even with a child-theme it looks like it's loading my old style.css - meaning I can't remove code from the css like i.e. #content tr { vertical-align: top; }

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a separate custom css file, commenting will obviously not work as your main css file will still contain some of the same style sets. So, to remove a style set entirely do the following on your custom CSS file.

`#content table {
display:none!important;
}`

You can do this for each style set or add them all together, separating them with a comma. i.e.

```
#content table, #content tr {
display:none!important;
}
```

In regards to the second part of your question, you can't remove just part of a style set but you can overwrite it by continuing to use the `!important` declaration and using opposite values such as changing padding from 24px to 0px if you don't want any padding. You will need to realign to your preference or set it to `baseline` which is the default. (Again, this goes in your custom css file)

```
#content tr td {
padding: 0px 0px!important;
vertical-align:baseline!important;
}
```

Notice that I didn't include `border-top: 1px solid transparent;` because your main CSS will still apply this part of the style so you only need to overwrite anything you don't want or wish to change on your custom CSS being that there is no way for you to comment style sets in the same manner as you would using a single CSS file.

If you've found it helpful please mark this as the accepted answer to your question. Thanks.